# Как создать menuconfig?

Tags: linux, config

Вопрос теоретического характера. Как вообще создается и работает меню `make menuconfig`? Как и куда он пишет свои параметры, как их считывает и учитывает компилятор/Makefile? Ведь, особенно в ядре, в коде должно быть учтено все (в плане конфигурации), а компилятор/Makefile должен эту конфигурацию как-то считать и использовать при компиляции. Меня интересует именно теоретическая сторона вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

Если кратко, то при вводе `make *config`:

- `make` собирает соответствующую утилиту (например, `mconf`) из [`scripts/kconfig/`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.7/source/scripts/kconfig) и запускает её
- Эта утилита читает файлы `Kconfig`, которые расположены по всему дереву исходников ядра, например, [такой](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.7/source/fs/xfs/Kconfig) и на их основе составляет для пользователя древовидное меню.
- При закрытии она сохраняет все эти параметры в файл `.config` в виде простого списка «ключ=значение» и коментариев:

  ```
   # ...
   CONFIG_XFS_FS=m
   CONFIG_XFS_QUOTA=y
   CONFIG_XFS_POSIX_ACL=y
   CONFIG_XFS_RT=y
   # CONFIG_XFS_WARN is not set
   # CONFIG_XFS_DEBUG is not set
   # ...
  ```

При последующем запуске сборки файл `.config` будет прочитан и доступен в виде переменных `make` для проверки из [`Makefile`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.7/source/fs/xfs/Makefile)'ов:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_XFS_FS)        += xfs.o
xfs-$(CONFIG_XFS_QUOTA)     += xfs_dquot.o \
                   xfs_dquot_item.o \
                   xfs_trans_dquot.o \
                   xfs_qm_syscalls.o \
                   xfs_qm_bhv.o \
                   xfs_qm.o \
                   xfs_quotaops.o

xfs-$(CONFIG_XFS_RT)        += xfs_rtalloc.o

xfs-$(CONFIG_XFS_POSIX_ACL) += xfs_acl.o

# ... и т.п.
```

А также на его основе будет сгенерирован `include/generated/autoconf.h`, в котором будут доступны все те же значения для препроцессора в виде `define`'ов:

```
// ...
#define CONFIG_XFS_QUOTA 1
#define CONFIG_XFS_RT 1
#define CONFIG_XFS_FS_MODULE 1
#define CONFIG_VXFS_FS_MODULE 1
#define CONFIG_XFS_POSIX_ACL 1
// ...
```

---

Также смотри:

- [Документация самого ядра](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/kbuild/index.html) по системе сборки

Comment: KBuild используется не только в ядре: Busybox, uClibc, BuildRoot, ...